# Trying to open modal on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I am trying to open ANTD modal when i click on button on the form using the below code

This is HTML code:

```
 <div>
    <Button type="primary" size={buttonsize.size} onClick={createproject1}>
      Add New Project
    </Button>
    <div>

  <div>
    <Modal
      title="Add New project"
      visible={setvisible.visible}
      onOk={handleOk}
      onCancel={handleCancel}
    > 
  <Input size="small"  placeholder="Project Name"  onChange={handleChange('projectName')} />
  <br />
  <br />
  <Input size="small"  placeholder="Project Number" onChange={handleChange('projectNumber')} />
  <br />
  <br />
  <Input size="small"  placeholder="Area" onChange={handleChange('area')} />
  <br />
  <br />
    </Modal>
  </div>
```

This is the hook and other state stuff:

```
const [visible, setvisible] = useState({ visible: false });

const createproject1 = (e) => {
  setvisible.visible = true;
};
```

I am not sure where i am going in wrong direction.. could any one please let me know is there any way to open a modal that would be very grateful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> Returns a stateful value, and a function to update it.

`setvisible` is a **function**, which allows you to update the state. You would need to call it like so:

```
setvisible({visible: true});
```

Since this is as simple as a bool, and object isn't necessary here:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
```

Then you could simply call:

```
setVisible(true);
```

Since you're still having issues, let me make this dirt simple for you:

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
```

And your component:

```
 <div>
    <Button type="primary" size={buttonsize.size} onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>
      Add New Project
    </Button>
    <div>

  <div>
    <Modal
      title="Add New project"
      visible={visible}
      onOk={handleOk}
      onCancel={handleCancel}
    > 
  <Input size="small"  placeholder="Project Name"  onChange={handleChange('projectName')} />
  <br />
  <br />
  <Input size="small"  placeholder="Project Number" onChange={handleChange('projectNumber')} />
  <br />
  <br />
  <Input size="small"  placeholder="Area" onChange={handleChange('area')} />
  <br />
  <br />
    </Modal>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for suggestion but i am getting error at this lane `visible={setvisible({visible: false})}`

Comment: `visible={() => setvisible({visible: true})}`

Comment: nope getting error at the same line `index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `visible` of type `function` supplied to `Modal`, expected `boolean`.
    in Modal (at Projectlist.js:151)`

Answer (score 0):

For creating hooks as single value variable, you don't have to create hooks like this..

```
const [visible, setvisible] = useState({ visible: false });
```

Instead use this...

```
const [visible, setvisible] = useState(false);
```

Here setVisible is Hooks function not an object..
So you cannot set visible value by setVisible.visible = true.
Rather you should have you write this :

```
setVisible(true)
```

and Use visible variable as visible attribute of modal .

```
 <Modal
  ...
  visible={visible}
  ...
>
```